# Datatables how to add some custom jquery code if one of the pagination buttons was pressed

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the datatables plugin for jquery and added some clickhandlers to my table but these are only created for the first page of my table. When I go to the next page, the rows has no clickhandlers. So I guess I need to add the clickhandlers each time when I go to the next page.

I do not know how I can do something when the next page button was pressed because the clickaction of this button comes from the plugin. How can I add my custom actions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should provide fnRowCallback function, and attach your handlers in it. This function will get called for each row before it is displayed.

Here is one [general example on fnRowCallback](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to handle pagination click event

```
$('#table_instance').bind('page', function () {
//call some function here
```

});